# jquery - required help in convert json to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have json data like this.

`[{"data":"85"},{"data":"83"},{"data":"75"},{"data":"87"},{"data":"86"},{"data":"0"},{"data":"84"}]`.

I wanted to remove the `"data":` and curly brackets.

I wanted the output to be like this.

`[85,83,75,87,86,0,84]`

Someone please help me on converting it to like that.

Comment: You need to know how to **access objects** in JS, and how to use a **for loop**. Enjoy your googling session!

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question with jQuery, so heres an answer using it:

```
var input = [{ "data": "85" }, { "data": "83" }, { "data": "75" }, { "data": "87" }, { "data": "86" }, { "data": "0" }, { "data": "84" }];
var output = $.map(input, function (e) { return e.data; });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = [];
jsonData.forEach(function(i) {
    newArray.push(i.data);
});
```

Where `jsonData` is the name of the variable storing your JSON data.

Comment: forEach is awefull why do people even use it ?

Comment: Why do you think that? Because of browser support?

Comment: many reasons. browsers supports, inability to break it(well not easy way)... etc

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array and extract data value like this

```
var obj= [{"data":"85"},{"data":"83"},{"data":"75"},{"data":"87"},{"data":"86"},{"data":"0"},{"data":"84"}];
var arr = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < obj.length;i++){
      arr.push(obj[i].data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code.

```
var myMessage = [{"data":"85"},{"data":"83"},{"data":"75"},{"data":"87"},{"data":"86"},{"data":"0"},{"data":"84"}];

var obj2 = eval(myMessage);
var myArray = new Array();
for(var i in obj2){
     myArray[i] = obj2[i].data;
}
console.log(myArray);
```

Cheers Subh

Answer (score 0):

```
var msg = '[{"data":"85"},{"data":"83"},{"data":"75"},{"data":"87"},{"data":"86"},{"data":"0"},{"data":"84"}]';
var msgObject = JSON.parse(msg);  
var output = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < msgObject.length; i++) {
  output.push(msgObject[i].data);
}
alert(JSON.stringify(outputObject));
```